# Proper way to invoke a method of a REST service (with multiple parameters)

Tags: rest, language-agnostic

So I have a method in the backend that I want to invoke from clients (Android and web, though not really important). The method accepts two "complex" arguments -- two objects.

Is it OK to simply declare a URL (e.g. `domain/method`) to which the clients POST the objects, and have a controller in the backend mapping to that URL and calling the method? If yes, how should I send a POST request with two objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you talk about domain/method it sounds more like an RPC service than a REST service. RPC (Remote Procedure Call) is for services that are method based whereas REST is for services that are resource based.

In any case, when you create a REST API, you should use URLs like the following:

example.com/resource/
example.com/resource

When you need to create a new resource, use the POST method on example.com/resource. You can include your objects in the payload of the POST request. The server should validate and process those objects ultimately generating a new resource. Depending on your REST architecture, the server can return the resource or the URI of the resource in the response to your post.

The way that you validate and process the objects and generate the resource depends on your application. Generally, you use the URI and HTTP method (GET, POST, PUT, or DELETE are standard) to route to the code that handles the request.

Comment: Oh :/ so it should be  *all* resources when doing REST? :/ what if a button on the client just needs to increment something (creates no new resources)?

Comment: Assuming that the item that needs to be incremented is a property of an existing resource, you can update it using PUT or PATCH.

Comment: Then what I would do is send a PUT/PATCH request with an empty body(?) to `example.com/resourceToUpdate`, and on the server have some code which is triggered for this URL and PUT/PATCH request which increments the property?

Comment: That's a reasonable solution if you need to keep the incremented property decoupled from the request. Since we're getting into some nitty gritty details, an explanation of the broader use case might be useful.

Comment: Before throwing the use case in, thank you very much for the answers and the patience so far :)
OK, so there's a **thing** which can be used only by one user at a time. Users reserve it in advance (**1**) and they can see how many others are waiting to use the **thing**. They can also give up waiting/cancel the reservation (**2**).

Now this incrementing/updating would be used in (1) and (2), i.e. the only thing that would have to be done when cancelling the reservation is decrement the number of users waiting for the **thing**